# Google Analytics, track same website with two different accounts, how?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

as the title says, how do I track a website with Google Analystics from two different accounts?

I made some research about this topic and found alot of old posts which were saying that you should include the different tracking codes at each side. But this can't be the best way, right?

Is it possible to do something like this?

***Old Code:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

***New Code:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-2']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

Thanks in advance Jack

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to track 2 websites on one Google Analytics account or do you want to track 1 website on 2 GA accounts? Why not just add an account to your existing GA account?

Comment: the last mentioned, I want to track one website with 2x analystics account

Comment: So you mean I can add an account to the other one, and they're able to see the data I can see?

Comment: Yes, you can add a user (email address) to your existing account and they can see the same data.

Comment: I see, but they can't edit any settings without my permission, right ;)?

Comment: Yes, you can set the permissions you want. If you just keep it default they can 'read and analyze' your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible without updating any old code. you have to add other account to primary account:

1. Click **Admin** at the top of Google Analytic page.
2. To show three column **Account**, **PROPERTY**, **VIEW**.
3. Select **USER MANAGEMENT** from **Account**, **PROPERTY**, **VIEW** base on access permission.
4. Enter **Email address** and assign roll.
5. check your secondary email address website tracking same as primary email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can track the same page on two different GA accounts using this code:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1'],   // First account
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-87654321-1'], // Second account
  ['b._trackPageview']
);
(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

This has always worked for us.